# Is it possible that run the opencv project in linux which didn't install opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, makefile

Now I have a opencv project which was build in Linux platform, and of course it can run successfully.

I want to  share the execution file of the project to other person(like boss), and other person's computer didn't install opencv

Is it possible to modified the makefile file to let the other person's computer run the project without installing opencv library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [link to static OpenCV libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5604061/23643) This way they are bundled with your executable, so the target system doesn't have to have shared libraries installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully built my executable with `RPATH=$ORIGIN`, which mean that I can put the openCV libraries in the same directory as the executable. This means they don't clash with existing openCV installations (or lack thereof)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the executable, you will need the libraries to process the image. So, those libraries must be present for the processing purpose either by providing them in your system or by linking them to your executable itself.