# Boost::Test : Compiling and running a "hello world" program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, program-entry-point, boost-test, linker-errors

I am trying to get a dummy Boost.test "hello world" program running. I found documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html) and [there](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools1_boost/index.html) but obviously there is something I am missing…

Here is what I have done :

### Step #1 : I installed the dependencies

```
sudo aptitude install libboost-test-dev
```

which installs both the headers (`libboost-test1.54-dev`) and the binary files (`libboost-test1.54.0`).

### Step #2 : Creating the source file to be compiled

I have one single file called `test.cpp` which contains :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

// EOF
```

as was recommended in the [official tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html)

### Step #3 : Compilation

I compile my code by calling :

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

I am not 100% sure about the option to link the library since the [official tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html) does not mention it explicitly. Yet, it seems to match the library file names I have in `/usr/lib`. Plus, the linker does not complain about not finding the shared object or static library files.

Which returns the following error :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### The issue

I quite agree with the linker : I don't see any `main()` function in my code… But where and how should I implement it ?

I am quite surprised because I was expecting to have to create a `runner.cpp` file defining function `main()` but the official [boost tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html) does not mention such a thing…

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529470/boost-unit-testing-main-function) suggests defining the `BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` macro, but the official boost tutorial does not mention it either. Is that the proper way of doing it ?

Could someone please give me clear step-by-step instructions on how to make my dummy "hello world" project compile ?

Comment: are you actually including the boost headers? shoudln't there be an `-I/usr/include` or something? I believe the boost test headers should provide a main for you... :hmmm: sorry it's been a while since I used boost::test, imo it's a bit over-engineered

Comment: By default, the compiler can include the header file `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` which is located in `/usr/include`. Hence `-I/usr/include` doesn't change a thing… Out of curiosity : what is your favourite unit testing framework ? (not that I'd like to start a flamewar ! (^.^) )

Comment: The official tutorial has been updated: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/intro.html uses the header only variant, and this section http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html introduces all variants

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to add `#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` before Boost.Test include.

Check [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation/standalone.html) - if library was built as dynamic (and it is usually so in many linux distributions), this macro is required. It makes header file define `int main()` - with static linking `main` is defined inside static library, but dynamic linking requires main to be in 'static' part of program. So this macro will make boost header 'inject' main into your cpp file and after compilation it will be there.

Comment: Yes (almost !) : compilation succeeds with `g++ test.cpp -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK -lboost_unit_test_framework` ! But running the outputted binary gives following error : `Test setup error: test tree is empty` whereas the official tutorial shows a successful output : `*** No errors detected`. What is the (hopefully) last missing step ?

Comment: BTW, in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` I have both files `libboost_unit_test_framework.so` and `libboost_unit_test_framework.a` : does that make sense ? Why leave the choice to the user ?

Comment: @GLorieul - probably tutorial is outdated - you need to define at least single test to see "No errors detected". As for .a lib - it might be only a wrapper that loads .so, or (as you suggest) - it's for those users who really need static linking

Comment: indeed, adding a test solves my issue ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: BTW the tutorial I was originally linking to was the tutorial for a previous version (v 1.43) of Boost::Test. Yet, its content has not been updated either in the tutorial relative to the [version I am using (1.54)][1] nor to the one concerning the [latest version (1.59)][2]. [1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html [2] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/practical_usage_recommendations/tutorials/bt_and_tdd.html

Answer (score 5):

Note : the following procedure is based in @Hcorg's answer and the subsequent discussion in the comments.

### Step #1 : Install the dependencies

In my case (Linux Mint 17.0 Qiana) :

```
sudo aptitude install libboost-test-dev
```

This installs both the headers (package `libboost-test1.54-dev`) and the binary files (package `libboost-test1.54.0`).

Both the static (`*.a`) and dynamic (`.so`) library files are being installed, which leaves the choice to the user (or compiler) to use either.

### Step #2 : Create the source file to be compiled

Create one single file called `test.cpp` which contains :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(dummy) {
    BOOST_CHECK(1 + 1 == 2);
}
```

If you are using Boost::Test v1.59 you should instead write :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE const_string test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(dummy) {
    BOOST_TEST(1 + 1 == 2);
}
```

This differs from the instructions in the [official tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/practical_usage_recommendations/tutorials/bt_and_tdd.html) (as of today 15th Oct 2015).

### Step #3 : Compilation

Compile the source file by calling either :

```
g++ test.cpp -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

if your compiler or yourself decide to use the dynamic library or

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

if your compiler or yourself decide to use the static library.

Compilation should succeed silently.

### Step #4 : Running the program

Calling

```
./a.out
```

should lead to following output :

```
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
```

Answer (score 1):

On your system, both static and shared libraries are installed by `aptitude` and this is known that in this case, `gcc` will prefer shared libraries. (see [making gcc prefer static libs to shared objects when linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604061/making-gcc-prefer-static-libs-to-shared-objects-when-linking) for example.)

You are hence building your boost.test module with the shared library variant

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html#boost_test.usage_variants.shared_lib
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/shared_lib_customizations.html

and this requires setting the macro `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` before any headers of boost.test.